# Is it better to use 0 or NULL as the default for MySQL INT fields that store dates?

Tags: php, mysql, null, int, default

I have to live with an INT in our date/time records in MySQL, so I'm trying to figure out whether it's better to use 0 or NULL as the default for those fields. We're migrating, and data is coming in as 0000-00-00 00:00:00, a Unix timestamp, 0, NULL, false, etc, so I'm converting everything through the PHP strtotime() and date() functions, but getting weird results on insert.

Ultimately I can end up with something usable in PHP, but I'm not sure whether after the fact which is better to use as the default in MySQL.

Comment: not sure it matters all that much as long as you are consistent. we usually go with null.

Answer (score 7):

`0` is a value. `NULL` is a lack of a value.

Use `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express the absence of a value, you should use `Null`.  0 in epoch time is equal to midnight on January 1, 1970.  Therefore, based on the description of your situation I would suggest using `Null`.

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered using NULL prevents selecting dates or ints as "less than this" because MySQL doesn't compare ints and nulls in this context. When I set them to 0 as the default, they came up in the select, which was what we wanted. I'm not sure what complications this will cause in the future (we may need to find an alternate solution) but right now it gets us the data we want.